# Removing non-system app using ADB shell in Android device

Tags: android, adb

I removed an app existing in data folder of my device using adb shell , but while installing the app from my code in device its showing error that can not install over already existing signature. As of now, no app or package exist in my device of the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install it with help of "pm install" (not adb install) and post error text here. Possibly it's not fully uninstalled (which is ridiculous but possible in some cases). Also you need to be sure that app signed with production key and (if it's preinstalled app) with vendor key. In other case it's work would be unpredictable.